Crack in wall under upper room window
My house is kind of old, made in the 70's and currently the wall in my bedroom upstairs has a long vertical crack and is horizontal at certain points. At first it was just a simple crack now the drywall is falling out in small pieces. The drywall when you touch it is separated from the wall inside and is chipping if you touch it. What should I do to fix this.
Please advise how to fix it and or how to find source of issue, greatly appreciated.
P.S Lot of humidity, and rainy weather and the windows get only opened during summer for obvious reasons.
Video of the cracked wall for easier perspective: https://vimeo.com/953508306
Upstairs wall under window cracking, drywall swelling and separating falling off



We could use a pic from farther away to make a better determination.  However it looks as if there is a leak that is allowing water in behind the drywall.  That must be fixed first.

@RMDman Hello, thank you for replying, what do you think is causing the leak, from the window itself or the roof? How would I check that, any advise is a greatly appreciated.

My young house (built in the 1890s) scoffs at the youth of your "kind of old" house. Just for some perspective. ;)

@Nami328, there is no way of telling where the leak is from based on the pics and video. You need an on site inspection.

It appears that there is water infiltration most likely from around the window.
That will need to be examined from the outside and corrected. You did not provide pics or video of the outside so I can only speculate. Look for cracks at any caulking. Look at the window trim for gaps especially at the top. Even the seals of glass to the frame can be the problem.
There may be an issue with the roof or siding, we really don't know since there is not a view.  Inspect it yourself or have someone knowledgeable about home construction take a look.
The water infiltration problem must be fixed first.  Then you can repair the drywall.  Let everything dry. Then scrape away any loose paint and loose drywall or spackling bits.  Patch the cracks with spackling or light drywall compound.  When dry sand lightly to feather the edges. Prime and paint.
If you have areas where the drywall is bulged, that area needs to be cut out and new drywall installed. This is a much larger repair. You will need to add wood support along the edges to screw in a new drywall piece. That needs to be taped and covered with compound, most likely in two seperate layers. Then sanded to feather and prime and paint.
